# MYSQL Pivoting rows to column

Tags: mysql, sql, workbench

i have created following table

```
CREATE TABLE `demo` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `A1` varchar(56) DEFAULT NULL,
  `B1` varchar(56) DEFAULT NULL,
  `C1` varchar(56) DEFAULT NULL,
  `D1` varchar(56) DEFAULT NULL,
  `E1` varchar(56) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(56) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

My insert query

```
 INSERT INTO `demo` VALUES
(1,'a','b','c','d','d','10');
(2,'a','c','d','a','c','11');
(3,'a','d','d','a','c','12');
```

Then after my table structure is here
[My table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qCes.png)

[i want output that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79uWx.png)

for this i have tried following

```
select `10`,`20`,`30` from
(
    (select A1,B1,C1,D1,E1 from demo where id =1) as `10`,
    (select A1,B1,C1,D1,E1 from demo where id =2) as `20`,
    (select A1,B1,C1,D1,E1 from demo where id =3) as `30`
)as s
```

i am getting following error

```
    Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
    that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 's' at line 6
```

please let me know what i am doing wrong ....or any other better approach to get this output

Comment: Excuse me! what are these? `one,two,three,four,five`

Comment: I didn't understand your output too!

Comment: @SubrataDeyPappu i have updated my question.please look at this

Comment: @SubrataDeyPappu i want mydata as pivoting.Can you please help me

Comment: can you send your expected result, your query is wrong at all

Comment: You do realize that `10` is now a table, and not a column ? please explain your logic

Comment: @GoudaElalfy my expected result is http://i.stack.imgur.com/79uWx.png

Comment: @Yossi i tried to get data from table bases on id then alias resulted data as 10,20,30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to want:

```
select max(case when id = 1 then val end) as `10`,
       max(case when id = 2 then val end) as `20`,
       max(case when id = 3 then val end) as `30`      
from ((select id, a1 as val, 1 as which from demo) union all
      (select id, b1, 2 as which from demo) union all
      (select id, c1, 3 as which from demo) union all
      (select id, d1, 4 as which from demo) union all
      (select id, e1, 5 as which from demo)
     ) x
group by which;
```

Comment: just for understanding him +1 !

Comment: @Gordon Linoff can you please explain your query and logic behind this

Comment: why are you using 1,2,3,4,5 here .Please let me know your logic for this

Comment: @user3172982 . . . The output has five rows, which need to be aggregated and ordered.  Hence the need for the sequential number.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks